# Trying to download flask-ask using pip but have received some errors due to incompatibility? Is there an alternative for this issue?

Tags: python, flask, flask-ask

I am trying to download flask-ask to use it with Alexa skills, but I keep getting errors.

I tried downgrading pip and that solution did not work either, as this was proposed on another forum post.

Complete output (5 lines):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/private/var/folders/1s/7h_kkk6j2vd1k2j7y5d4yhw40000gn/T/pip-install-hiTsf7/flask-ask/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip.req import parse_requirements
ImportError: No module named req

----------------------------------------
```

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.

I expect to get the flask-ask dependency downloaded.